# Custom Chrome Tab OAuth intercept redirect_uri

Tags: android, google-chrome, oauth, chrome-custom-tabs

I can't seem to figure out how to intercept the redirect_uri that I use with Fitbit OAuth 2.0.

Here's the intent-filter that I defined for one of my Activities:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="track" android:host="fitbit"/>
</intent-filter>
```

After logging in and authorizing the user using a Custom Chrome Tab, I'm redirected to track://fitbit URI that I'd like to intercept and send that intent to my Activity, but the redirect_uri is loaded in the Tab itself, showing the "ERR_UKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" error.

**EDIT #1:**

Found a similar discussion at
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=536037. I cleared the defauls from Chrome, but the redirect_uri of the tab doesn't seem to fire an Intent asking which app to open the URI with.

Comment: I think that google fixed with the latest chrome update (48+). Have you tried it again since this release ?